# 'webdriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, path, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use selenium and I keep getting the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jensa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\jensa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\jensa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seleniumtest.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
  File "C:\Users\jensa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\jensa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'webdriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I'm really confused as nothing online is helping me. The folder to the chromedriver IS in the PATH.

I've tried having the python file in the same folder as the driver and in a different folder.

I've tried specifying the location via executable_path. I've tried including and not including '.exe' in the executable_path. Nothing works. Can someone please help me get this working. Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = r"\C:\bin\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide chrome driver binary path , please download latest chrome driver which support to your browser version :
you can download  [Latest Chrome driver from here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\bin\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("url")
```

Comment: I have downloaded it before i even started

Comment: @TabulateJarl8 should be chromedriver.exe, check updated solution

Comment: yep, the path to the file is C:\bin\chromedriver.exe and I added C:\bin into my PATH variable

Comment: Heres a screenshot of my path variables: https://imgur.com/4HEDxow

Comment: You are setting up environemnt variable and in the script also you are passing absolute path so whats the use to setting up environment variable. its not required tbh. Also navigate to C:\bin\ and check chromedriver.exe is present in it and double click on it after that will launch cmd prompt and you can see session is created. When you see Message: 'webdriver' executable needs to be in PATH. message that means  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" binary path")

Answer (score 0):

*If it is in the `PATH` then no need for referencing in your code.*

*Simply write your code the following*

> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
> driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
> ```

Comment: @TabulateJarl8 have you tried restarting your computer?